# How to update document in an object in an array in an object in an array using MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using MongoDB queries:
1. How do I find the object with `_id A3`?
2. How would I update object with `_id A3` to `A4`?
**Please note:** Database is an array of objects where one key has an array of objects

```js
[{
"project_name": "ProjectA",
"issues":[{"issue_title":"TitleA1", "_id":"A1"},
          {"issue_title":"TitleA2","_id":"A2"},
          {"issue_title":"TitleA3","_id":"A3"}]
},
{
"project_name": "ProjectB",
"issues":[{"issue_title":"TitleB1", "_id":"B1"},
          {"issue_title":"TitleB2","_id":"B2"},
          {"issue_title":"TitleB3","_id":"B3"}]
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) your object by nested `_id` and use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote nested object to the top level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$issues"
    },
    {
        $match: { "issues._id": "A3" }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{ newRoot: "$issues" }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6UMpI1JBRhj)

the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) can be used to update that one:

```
db.col.updateOne({ "project_name": "ProjectA", "issues._id": "A3" }, { $set: { "issues.$._id": "A4" } })
```

Comment: I'm not sure that works because the starting dataset is an array... could you please confirm that your code can bypass 2 arrays? I'm not sure if I'm testing the code wrong or if the code can't access double arrays. Maybe it needs $elemMatch somewhere but I tried so many times and couldn't get it to work

Comment: So is it like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8yPdPJ1C2cB ? or can you show exactly how single object looks like?

Comment: Ah yes, just like in that playground. Question 1 would be how to return this object {"issue_title":"TitleA3","_id":"A3"} by itself. I tried the code you suggested but it's giving me error and maybe we need to integrate "aggregate" somehow?

Comment: @wongz modified my answer

Comment: thanks, the first code works. The second one may need aggregate as well?